# JCE padding not being properly encrypted/decrypted

Tags: java, encryption, jce

I am working on a program that I will use to encrypt and decrypt files using the JCE. My encryption and decryption is working correctly in default mode (ECB/PKCS5PADDING) however when I try to use CBC and I decrypt my file I am getting some of the text being junk (or when I try an image it gets corrupted.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? (I have not included my imports, can add if necessary)

```
public class encwork {
private static String keyString = "ykHySDZCWr16TVku"; //Encryption key
private static void bulkWork(int cipherMode, File inputFile, File outputFile) throws Exception{
    //Let the user enter the key they wish to use
    Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyString.getBytes(), "AES"); //Generates a key based on the default keysize for the specified algorithm

    //Generate an Initialization Vector (IV)
    final int ALG_KEYLENGTH = 128; //Change this as desired for the security level you want
    byte[] iv = new byte[ALG_KEYLENGTH / 8]; //Save the IV bytes or send it in plaintext with the encrypted data so you can decrypt the data later
    SecureRandom prng = new SecureRandom(); //Use SecureRandom to generate random bits. The size of the IV matches the blocksize of the cipher
    prng.nextBytes(iv); //Construct the appropriate IvParameterSpec object for the data to pass to Cipher's init() method

    //Create a Cipher by specifying the following parameters: Alg name, Mode (CBC), Padding (PKC7/PKCS5)
    Cipher cipherForEncryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"); // Must specify the mode explicitly as most JCE providers default to ECB mode

    //Initialize the Cipher for Encryption
    cipherForEncryption.init(cipherMode, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

    //Declare / Initialize the Data, Convert the Input to Bytes and encrypt or decrypt using doFinal.
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
    inputStream.read(inputBytes);
    byte[] outputBytes = cipherForEncryption.doFinal(inputBytes);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    outputStream.write(outputBytes);
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Crypto/In/test.txt"); 
    File encryptedFile = new File("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Crypto/Enc/test.encrypted");
    File decryptedFile = new File("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Crypto/Dec/testdec.txt");

    //Encryption
    try {
        encwork.encrypt(inputFile, encryptedFile); //Encrypt method
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //Will show what caused the error in the console if an error occurs
    }

    //Decryption
    try {
        encwork.decrypt(encryptedFile, decryptedFile); //Decrypt method
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //Will show what caused the error in the console if an error occurs
    }
}

public static void encrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile) throws Exception {
    bulkWork(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, inputFile, outputFile); //ENC_MODE = Constant used to initialize cipher to encryption mode.
}

public static void decrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile) throws Exception {
    bulkWork(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, inputFile, outputFile); //ENC_MODE = Constant used to initialize cipher to encryption mode.
}}
```

Comment: What does "some of the text being junk" mean? Perhaps the first 16-bytes?

Comment: @zaph Basically my test file is just a text file with "this is a test written" over and over, but when I decrypt the file the first line is "çQßs}@ LÂ¤qMä]this is a test". I think it is a padding issue as when I use the default encryption/decryption (ECB) I do not have this issue.

Comment: Padding is at the end of the encrypted data, not the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the same IV for both encryption and decryption.

From the comment that the decryption starts: "the first line is "çQßs}@ LÂ¤qMä]this is a test" that would mean the IV for encryption and decryption is not the same.

This comment says it all:

*//Save the IV bytes or send it in plaintext with the encrypted data so you can decrypt the data later*

Either:

1. save the IV by returning it from the encryption and passing it in on decryption

or

2. prefix the encrypted data with the IV and on decryption split it off to use for decryption. (The IV does not need to be secret)

More on the IV and CBC mode, see [Cipher Block Chaining (CBC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29):

While the IV influences the entire encrypted data CBC mode is self correcting and this means only the first block is incorrect when the wrong IV is used on decryption.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.

Please excuse my ignorance as I have only started working with the JCE recently, but what do I need to change in my code to ensure the same IV is being used?

Comment: See  2. in the answer for a reasonably standard method. In short simply write the IV to the file before the first encrypted data. On decryption read the first 16-bytes and use that as the IV, start decryption the data right after that.

Comment: does that mean that in my encrypt and decrypt functions that I need to be taking my key and IV as input along with the input and output files?

Comment: Yes, write two functions. It is better to write two functions, the more conditionals the more confusing and more errors. Since the IV does not need to be secret and should be different for each encryption it is easiest to just put it at the start of the encrypted data in the file.

Comment: honestly I'm a bit confused and I'm unsure how to do that. Would it be possible for you to help show me where in my code I should make changes to ensure I am using the same IV for encryption and decryption.

Comment: In the encryption function create a random IV. Write the IV to the file and then write the encrypted data to the file. In the decryption function read the first 16-bytes and set the IV to that, then decrypt the rest of the bytes.I don't write Java, the best I can do is in Swift and probably not very useful to you: [AES encryption in CBC mode with a random IV](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/7026/aes-encryption#t=201704181224404186557) in the Documentation section.

Comment: Thanks very much, really appreciate the help.